# Can kafka connect with interbase using JDBC connector interclient.jar using confluent platform

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, interbase

Is it possible for kafka to connect with interbase database using interclient.jar. I am not able to connect it in ubundu system, even after placing it in right folder.
This is my POST command to create the connector.

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --data "{ \"name\": \"ib_connector\",\"config\": { \"connector.class\": \"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector\", \"tasks.max\": 1,\"connection.url\": \"jdbc:interbase://remoteip:3050/TEST2.gdb?user=SYSDBA&password=masterkey\",\"mode\": \"timestamp+incrementing\", \"incrementing.column.name\": \"id\",\"timestamp.column.name\": \"modified\", \"topic.prefix\": \"test-interbase-\", \"poll.interval.ms\": 1000 } }" http://localhost:8083/connectors.
```

I have placed the JDBC connector `interclient.jar` file in `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`.

In `docker-compose.yml` the plugin path is set as  `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH:'/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars'`.

I also have `.env` file in which
`KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH=/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/` and `CLASS_PATH=usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/`.

The error message i am getting is as following.

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:interbase://remoteip:3050/TEST2?user=SYSDBA&password=masterkey for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:interbase://remoteip:3050/TEST2?user=SYSDBA&password=masterkey\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:interbase://remoteip:3050/TEST2?user=SYSDBA&password=masterkey
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail -- "I am not able to connect" presumably means you get an error message?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker, then putting a JAR on your *local filesystem* into `/usr/share/java` won't make Docker pick it up without a volume mapping. To avoid confusion, I would suggest to move your host files elsewhere.

`KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH` doesn't mean anything to the Confluent Docker image either.

Make some other local directory locally. Put your JDBC JAR in there, then add a volume to the Compose file to point to the JDBC connect location in the container

```
volumes:
  - /path/to/your_folder:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/lib:ro
```

Where `ls /path/to/your_folder` shows the JDBC driver you want to use, and if you have Java installed, you can run `jar -tf /path/to/your_folder/example.jar` to verify there is a JDBC Driver class that is trying to be loaded in that file.

That setup has worked [in my repo](https://github.com/cricket007/kafka-connect-sandbox/blob/master/kafka-connect/README.md) when I tried MSSQL JDBC driver

Comment: i have added the volumes as following and put ` .jar` file in a directory locally. Then removed `KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH`  from `.env file`.                     
         volumes:                                                                                                               
      - ${KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH}:/home/user/kafka/interclient  
      - /home/user/kafka/interclient:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/  . Still i am not able to connect . I am doing something wrong. Please help

Comment: Notice in my answer I put `/lib:ro` at the end, and therefore not overwriting the entire folder of  `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`

Comment: Yes i did the same.I have added /lib:ro at the end.  I am not able to edit comment properly. Sorry for this

Comment: If it still says `No suitable driver`, I'm not sure. If you get a connection error, then that is a separate issue and the JAR file in that path worked fine

Comment: And if you have removed `KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH` from `.env` file. then you will not be able to use `${KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH}` in Compose...

Comment: I have added `KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH` in compose as well as `.env` file. Still it is not working.

Comment: You do not need this variable. Start simple, and remove it. And so `${KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH}:/home/user/kafka/interclient` doesn't need to be in the YAML

Comment: I removed `${KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH}:/home/user/kafka/interclient` from `.yml` file and `.env` file has `CONFLUENT_VERSION=5.0.1
KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH=/home/user/kafka/interclient/
KAFKA_MANAGER_VERSION=latestELK_VERSION=6.5.1` parameters. But the post command is still not working. :(

Comment: I still do not know what all is inside of `/home/user/kafka/interclient/` folder or if you exec into the container after a restart (because editing the YAML doesn't immediately change volume mounts), and run `ls -lR /usr/share/java/kafka-connect/jdbc`, then you will need to check if it is indeed there

Comment: The folder `/home/user/kafka/interclient/` has only interclient.jar file. Other plugins are in  `usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`

Comment: Where can I get this JAR file? I don't know Interbase, or even if it works with Kafka

Comment: You can get it from here [link](https://www.dbschema.com/interbase-jdbc-driver.html)

Comment: And how would I setup an interbase database on a Mac to test if this works without having to create an account?

Comment: I have no idea how to install  it in mac. My docker is in ubuntu system and interbase is in remote system. Sorry for this :(

Comment: Alroght, well, the JAR is there in the Docker setup, and I think `jdbc:interbase` is correct on all the documentation I can find, but without having this system available to test, I'm afraid I can't be much more help

Comment: I can understand. Thanks for your help i did try the way you said. But i think the issue is something else.. I think nobody has tried to connect interbase with kafka.